# Python/Discord Username changes prevents my bot from recognizing players

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am setting up a discord game which uses folders as profiles, how do I fix the problem that if someone changes their username the bot can no longer access their profile?

Comment: Users do have persistent IDs that won't change; use those instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usernames can be changed however User ID's cannot so you should use those instead, here's an example:

```
@client.command()
async def getUserID(ctx):
    userID = ctx.author.id
    await ctx.send(f"Your User ID is {userID}")
```

Comment: Thank you, was struggling to find this code anywhere else.

Comment: No worries, if it helped make sure to mark the answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the UserID instead of the Username.

This never changes unless they change to a different account, so you won’t have to worry about usernames changing.